# How to search for ${foo} and replace by <c:out value="${foo}"/> in Eclipse editor?

Tags: regex, eclipse, jsp, escaping, el

Is there a regex to replace the outer part of a string while keeping the inner part?

before:

`${person.dog.name}`

after:

`<c:out value="${person.dog.name}"/>`

I need to use it in Eclipse editor, and the inner part changes.

---

This can be useful too:

Search: `\$\{(.*?)\}`

Replace:`\$\{fn:escapeXml\($1\)\}`

```
${person.dog.name}
```

become

```
${fn:escapeXml(person.dog.name)}
```

Comment: Be warned that regex replacements propsed so far will fail hard on constructs like `<c:if test="${bean.foo == 'bar' and bean.bar == 'foo'}">`, `<c:forEach>`, etc. You don't want to wrap that `${}` around with `<c:out>` or `fn:escapeXml()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find expression with:

```
(\$\{[^\}]+\})
```

and replace expression will be:

```
<c:out value="$1"/>
```

To find `${person.dog.name}` with `<c:out value="${person.dog.name}"/>` in Eclipse editor!

**Edit:**

Be careful while using it, because `<c:if test="${foo}">` will end up like `<c:if test="<c:out value="${foo}" />">`

Comment: OP is merely asking how to use it in Eclipse's search&replace, not in Java code (most likely as part of the process to fix completely overseen XSS attack holes in a bunch of JSP files).

Comment: Well, fix the answer then? Or just delete if you can't.

Comment: How about things like `<c:if test="${foo}">` in the JSP? This way they would end up like `<c:if test="<c:out value="${foo}" />">` which is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Just capture the entire string with `^(.*)$` and then use in the replace function use a back reference like `<c:out value="$1"/>` where the `$1` is the backreference

```
string.replaceAll("^(.*)$", "<c:out value=\"$1\"/>")
```

In eclipse  [see link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/shared/ref-findreplace.htm). You'd put `^(.*)$` into `find`, `<c:out value="$1"/>` into replace. select regular expressions, click find and replace.

If you're looking to capture all the `${foo}` with `<c:out value="${foo}"/>?` in some larger text then you'll have to use the regex `([$]{foo})` to find all the desired text then use `<c:out value=\"$1\"/>` in the replace field.

Comment: OP is asking how to use it in Eclipse's search&replace on JSP files, not in Java code.

Comment: Still then, you seem to be expecting that the whole JSP file contains solely an EL expression. Your regex one is namely a "match-all". It does not match individual `${...}` parts which are by itself not already inside a tag such as `<c:out>` or even e.g. `<c:if>` (where this replacement is not necessary).

Comment: Perhaps I misread the question where it states the input string is `${person.dog.name}` and the resulting string is `<c:out value="${person.dog.name}"/>`

Comment: That string is part of JSP file source code. Perhaps you just don't know what a JSP file is? I see that you're famliar with PHP (and probably ASP). Well, a JSP file is like a PHP or ASP file. But a PHP file doesn't contain solely a `echo $foo` nor does an ASP file contain solely a `<%=foo%>`, right? The same way, a JSP file doesn't contain solely a `${foo}`. OP is trying to fix XSS attack holes by putting several instances of it each inside `<c:out>` (like as you'd need to use `htmlspecialchars()` in PHP).