# Regular expression to match and replace "${foo}" but not "<c:if test="${foo}" />" in Java

Tags: java, regex, jsp, jakarta-ee, replace

While anyone will explore [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047789/how-to-search-for-foo-and-replace-by-cout-value-foo-in-eclipse-edito/17048652#17048652), the obvious question arises that, is there any regular expression possible that matches

```
${foo}
```

but not

```
<c:if test="${foo}" />
```

or

```
<c:when test="${foo}" />
```

to replace those stand alone `${foo}` with `<c:out value="${foo}" />`, here `foo` can be any string as long as `${foo}` is a valid [el expression](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm) in `jsp`.

*Edit:*

`${foo}` can be anywhere as long as its not violating `jsp` syntax after the replacement! This is just a precaution to prevent [XXS attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465583/alternative-to-using-cout-to-prevent-xss) in `jsp`'s.

Comment: so just ${foo} but without `"`?

Comment: How about when `${foo}` is inside a string of some other tag?

Comment: Uhm wait, this seems to be JSP; why do you need to parse your JSPs?

Comment: Because, stand alone el expresson like this, is vulnerable to XSS attack.

Comment: Interesting... Do you have a link? (btw, you should ask that to the question, among with the link... That makes for an interesting question)

Comment: @fge `<c:out>` basically escapes special characters like <,>,/,\,& etc. typically used in XSS attacks like injecting javascript with <script> tags into foo.

Comment: Yes but still: it'd be interesting to have a link, or at least that you add an example of such an exploit in the post

Comment: @fge, I edited the question with a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

This regex will find the naked `${foo}` which is not inside a `<c:.... test="${foo}" />` block

Regex: `(?!("))\$\{[^}]*\}(?!")`

Replace with `<c:out value="$0" />`

[image]

Input text: `<c:if test="${foo man chu}" />${foo bar}more text here`

Output Text: `<c:if test="${foo man chu}" /><c:out value="${foo bar}" />more text here`

---

To handle the additional edge cases where `${foo.bar}` might be inside ` tags then you might want to use this regex

Regex: `(?!("))(\$\{[^}]*\})(?!")|(<a\b[^>]*\bhref=")(\$\{[^}]*\})(")`

Replace with: `$3<c:out value="$1$2$4" />$5`

[image]

Input text: `<c:if test="${foo man chu}" />${foo bar}more <a href="${foo.name}" />text here`

Output text: `<c:if test="${foo man chu}" /><c:out value="${foo bar}" />more <a href="<c:out value="${foo.name}" />" />text here`

Comment: Yes, you are right, Your regex will find naked `${foo}`, but `<a href="${foo.name}" />` this type of replacable `${foo}` will be ignored.

Comment: That edge case wasn't included in the original sample text. Please see the updated response which addresses additional edge case.

Answer (score 1):

Following regex should work on your examples:

```
\${[^}]*}(?![^<>]*>)
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/ICdR4TGQXu

Though I think this might still give false positive for some rare cases.

Comment: Yes, you are right, your expression fails to detect `<a href="${foo.name}" />`, But still so close!

Comment: Its been long time since I wrote some JSTL but wouldn't `<a href="${foo.name}" />` be wrapped in some `<c: ... />`  also.

Comment: You'd rather want to replace it by `<a href="${fn:escapeXml(foo.name)}" />` instead of `<a href="<c:out value="${foo.name}" />" />`. So a different regex (or simply a different replacement) would be needed for that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're probably trying to edit your JSPs in a text editor that supports find by regex feature. Trying to parse your JSPs otherwise (like @fge pointed) wouldn't be wise though.

Here's a regex that would match `${foo}` but not `="${foo}"`

```
(?<!=")\${foo}(?!")
```

effectively eliminating a match on `<c:if test="${foo}" />` or `<c:when test="${foo}" />`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<!<c:(if|when) test=[\"'])\\$\\{foo}", "<c:out value=\"\\${foo}\" />");
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, regular expressions are not powerful enough to correctly process any non-trivial language, especially one that allows matching parentheses, escaped quotes, and nested quoting.

You may find a regular expression here that seems to work for most cases, but that likely just means that you haven't met a clever enough attacker yet.

You need to be much more restrictive about what you let your users enter.  You should not accept JSP code, try to "clean it up", and then execute it.  You **will** get exploited.  Even Sun could not accomplish this (see: the recent string of attacks against the Java Applet sandbox).